# Find the number of bijections using graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ where $V = \{1, 2, ..., n \}$ and $E = \{\{i, j\}: |i-j| = 1 \lor |i-j| = n-1\}$. Calculate the number of
bijections $f: V \to V$ $\text{ such for every }$ $p, q \in V $ $\text { if p is adjacent to q then f(p) or f(q) is even}$.**

What I tried doing was to find the set E which should be set of all adjacent numbers and {n, 1} since $|i-j| = n-1$.
$$E = \{\{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, ..., \{n, n-1\}, \{n, 1\}\}$$

But according to the condition, f(p) or f(q) must be even, that means i, j pairs can only be odd-odd or even-even numbers which is not possible since they are all in sequence, we can only have odd-even numbers with an exception of the last $\{n, 1\}$ which can be even if n is odd.

I'm not sure how to go on about solving this problem.

Edit:

I understand that either of the 2 vertices must be even, so according to the condition, edge set can be $E = \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, ..., \{n, n-1\}, \{n, 1\}\}$ if n is even else $E = \{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, ..., \{n, n-1\}\}$ So if we write **x** as set of all odd numbers in V and **y** as set of all even numbers in V, $x \to y$ is the required relation which is $\frac{n}{2}+1$ bijections if n is odd else $\frac{n}{2}$ bijections.

Comment: Hint: no such bijections exist when $n$ is odd. When $n$ is even, prove that the list $f(1),f(2),\dots$ must alternate between even and odd.

Comment: taking any vertex $x \in V$ must be adjacent to another vertex $y \in V$ only if x - 1 = y or 1 - x = y, assuming x was even, this would imply y is odd and vice versa. If we have n integers, $\frac{n}{2}$ must be odd and other half must be even, since an odd vertex can only be mapped to an even vertex or the other way around, we have $\frac{n}{2}$ bijections?

Comment: There are many more than $n/2$ bijections. There will be factorials involved.

Comment: If 1 is mapped to 2 there's only one way for every other n - 1 number to be mapped, since it's a bijection. If 1 is mapped to n, we have numbers from 2 to n -1 which is basically the same thing? What am I missing here?

Comment: You seem to be counting "graph isomorphisms" rather than bijections. There is no reason $f(2)$ has to be adjacent to $f(1)$, so there are lots of choices for how the numbers $2$ through $n-1$ are mapped.

Comment: I can't seem to find it, more help or solution would be appreciated.